# Заполнение таблиц на основе прошлого опыта (машинное обучение, нейронные-сети)

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Есть дата фрейм с тысячами строк, оранжевые столбцы (имеют неизменные значения их порядка 10 на каждый столбец) были проставлены вручную исходя из информации в желтом столбце, на данный момент накопился значимый объем таких данных и появилась идея автоматизировать процесс заполнения оранжевых столбцов.
Полазив по интернету понял, что необходимо смотреть в сторону машинного обучения или нейронной сети (так и не разобрался одно и тоже ли это или разные вещи), чтобы разобраться в данном вопросе по конкретной задаче нужно четкое направление куда смотреть, ведь если изучать всю тему может уйти несколько лет для написания 20 строк кода.
Что почитать? С чего начать чтоб максимально быстро решить именно эту задачу?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: уточните пожалуйста - что за значения в столбце `б/с` и какой они природы? Например могут ли различаться значения в столбце `б/с` для одинаковых значений в столбце `Блок`?

Comment: Для стобца Блок есть порядка 12 конкретных значений, тоже самое касается для Б/С это балансовый счет там порядка 8 неизменяемых значений

Answer (score 4):

Если рассматривать автоматическое заполнение столюба `Блок` - это классическая задача по классификации текста.

По поводу столбца `б/с` - трудно что-то сказать не понимая его природу.

> Что почитать?

Советую поискать статьи на следующие темы

- классификации текста
- векторизации текста
- doc2vec
- TF-IDF

Основная идея заключается в том, что исходный текст нужно сначала превратить в числовую матрицу. А дальнейшая обработка будет зависеть от выбранного алгоритма классификации.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то бухучет -  не самое благодатное поля для использования машинного обучения. Дело в том, что в МО всегда допускается определенный процент ошибочных решений. Больший-меньший, но надо смириться, с тем, что есть. А вот в бухучете зафигачит нейросеть не тот номер счета. А потом придет налоговая. Кто отвечать за ошибки будет?
С другой стоны, если перепроверять решение нейросети, то зачем тогда вообще ее использовать? Так даже трудозатраты не сократить.

Подумайте над этим вопросом. Тем более, на сколько я понял вам для того, что-бы прикрутить к задаче любое решение (ну, кроме очевидного: "если в тексте столбца А есть словосочетание "продажа металлолома" то в б/c пишем 91") то объем знаний, который вам придется предварительно освоить -  очень не детский. Ну или нанять специально наученного специалиста -  а это не дешево, а с учетом сказанного выше - еще и вряд-ли окупится.

Comment: Ну, всё не так уж плохо. Во-первых проверять машинную разметку проще, чем делать всё самому с нуля. Во-вторых алгоритм может хорошо размечать одни категории и плохо другие, соответственно, в каких-то категориях можно полностью положиться на машинную разметку, а какие-то перепроверять, но это всё-равно будет меньший объём работ, чем всё вручную делать.

Comment: @CrazyElf, и в третьих, бухгалтера тоже нередко ошибаются ;) Главное отличие бухгалтера от нейросети - она/он способна самостоятельно проверять и исправлять собственные ошибки. Я думаю со временем можно обучить и этому

Comment: Вопрос то в другом.  Главное отличие бухгалтера от нейросети -  первый отвечает за ошибку своей головой. А вторая никак. Кого посадят за ошибку? Ну или хотя-бы кто восполнит убыток, если что?

Comment: @passant А если эксель сглючит - кого посадят? )  Машинное обучение - это инструмент. Просто новый, современный. Вопросы ответственности и раньше как-то решали, не вижу, чем машинное обучение так сильно отличается от других инструментов автоматизации.

Comment: @ CrazyElf Если EXCEL сглючит -  это равносильно арифметической ошибке бухгалтера при ручном расчете. И в бухучете есть свои "заклинания" против таких вещей - система двойных счетов, еще всякое шаманство (давно я этим не занимался, так что за термины не ручаюсь). Но это совершенно не то, если нейросеть даст  неправильную  рекомендацию (причем -  гарантированно рано или поздно даст). Тут же ее не перепроверишь. Тем более, она сама не объяснит, почему она дала такое решение. Можно ли НС искать ошибки в решениях другой НС -  не знаю, даже намека не встречал на такую задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже пытаюсь классифицировать текст, пока не получается.В своей группе вк (https://vk.com/net_search) я писал о сложности работы с anaconda, она например может обеспечить пакет gensim, который может представить каждое слово в виде некоторого вектора заданной длины, потом такую матрицу пытался отдавать сети, но так как сеть обычная(а не сверточная), она требовала вектор для окончательного тестирования, поэтому и обучать ее надо было по векторам(как целый текст), это получилось как среднее по рядам такой матрицы, но при обучении на рекурентной сети ошибка упала, а проверку(оценку) на тренировочных данных (2 вектора) не прошла, поэтому я и говорю что не смог обучить.(мой блог на cyberforum - https://www.cyberforum.ru/blogs/763551/ )